# How do we check if there are no more active threads other than main thread?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a little c# app with multiple threads runing, but my main thread has to wait for all of threads to finish then it can do the rest. 
problem now is that im using .join() for each thread, this seems wait for each thread to finish then it goes to next thread, which makes app not really multi-threading and take long time to finish.

so I wonder if there is any way I can get around this problem or just a way to check if there are no more threads is active.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Task, it's pretty easier

Comment: isnt task same as threading?  it still run one task at each time?

Comment: No, it's not the same, Task is not Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye, as said by Cuong Le, using Task Parallel Library would be much efficient.
However, you can Create a list of Threads and then check if they are alive or not.

```
var threadsList = new List<Thread>();

threadsList.Add(myThread); // to add

bool areDone = true;
foreach (Thread t in threadsList) { 
    if (t.IsAlive)
    {
        areDone = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (areDone)
{
    // Everything is finished :O
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this one first. in the meantime, could you please show me an example of task?

Comment: Ok, I will add another answer soon using TPL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hanging on to the Thread object, you can use `Thread.IsAlive`.

Alternately, you might want to consider firing an event from your thread when it is done.

Comment: i want to run multiple at same time, but wait for them to finish, then do the rest

Comment: i did use .join in main thread, but i have 20 threads, each join() actually tells main thread to wait until it finishes, so 20 threads runs one by one in that case.........

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) doesn't mean your application isn't multithreaded - it tells the current thread to wait for the other thread to finish, which is exactly what you want.

Doing the following:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

/** create each thread, Start() it, and add it to the list **/

foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
  thread.Join()
}
```

**will** continue to run the other threads, except the current/main thread (it will wait until the other threads are done).

Just use `Thread.Join()`

Comment: i did use join(), but performance is bad, took 1 and half hr to finish all, but if i run each individual thread manually, it takes less than 10 mins. that's why I am under impression join() causing issues

Comment: @user1225072, you want to start all the threads, and *then* join them all. It sounds like you're joining each one right after you start it.

Comment: If you start each thread and join it before starting the next thread, it's not multithreaded. Be sure to start all threads before joining any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Run multiple at same time but wanted to wait for all of them to finish, here's a way of doing the same with Parallel.ForEach:

```
var arrStr = new string[] {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"};
Parallel.ForEach<string>(arrStr, str =>
{
    DoSomething(str); // your custom method you wanted to use
    Debug.Print("Finished task for: " + str);
});
Debug.Print("All tasks finished");
```

That was the most simplest and efficient i guess it can go if in C# 4.0 if you want all tasks to run through same method

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

It raises an event in the main thread (`RunWorkerCompleted`) after its work is done

Here is one sample from previously answered question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551376/148697